# Extract Nested Array/Struct Spark DataFrame

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a JSON file with contents that look like this:

```
{
  "dates_included":["2016-01-29"],
  "data":[
    {"field1":"2016-01-29","field2":"3 12 -72"},
    {"field1":"2016-01-29","field2":"33 12 -72"}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to create a new DataFrame that contains `field1` and `field2` as the two columns of the DataFrame.

I can load the JSON file into a DataFrame and register a temp table.  But unable to extract `field1` and `field2` into a new DataFrame.

Intial DataFrame schema looks like this:

```
root
 |-- data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- field1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- dates_included: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```